# MySQL Event update on every snapped 5 min

Tags: javascript, mysql

I was using the following MySQL event to update the table with the (CURRENT_TIME)+5) every five min. however my plan is was to get the table updated with that time every full 5 min from current time:
e.g., on 12:05 it writes 12:10, on 12:10 it writes 12:15...
So I used to fire the below event at exactly 12:30:00 for example in order to get it accurate.

```
CREATE EVENT x_next
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
DO
UPDATE data SET x_next= CONCAT(CONCAT(HOUR(CURRENT_TIME),':'),MINUTE(CURRENT_TIME)+5);
```

What I am looking now is to make it more accurate to make this event act like the following JSfiddle result where if the even started at any time it will update only on the next 5 min (snapped-to):

http://jsfiddle.net/v06jrobg/

Where the result should be what the event should update.
I am wondering if anyone had this experience before or any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define a start time instead of `current_timestamp`

```
CREATE EVENT x_next
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
STARTS '2014-10-08 12:00:00'
DO
UPDATE data SET x_next= 
CONCAT(HOUR(DATE_ADD(Now(),INTERVAL +5 MINUTE)),':',
MINUTE(DATE_ADD(Now(),INTERVAL +5 MINUTE)));
```

This will start at `12:00:00` and execute every 5 minute.

I changed your update syntax a bit also. It makes sure that the hour is added with 5 minutes, in case at `16:55` , the next value is `17:00`. I think this will give 17:0 and not 17:00, might have to fix a check for that. A bit hacky but it might do the trick?